# Sort List of Files Paths by Date Modified in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io

I'm trying to sort a list of files by date. I currently have a string array of file paths and I need to sort them by date modified. I've tried to the following, but with little luck. I don't really understand how the sort_by method works either.

```
@files.sort_by {|filename| File.mtime(filename) }
```

EDIT

I've also tried converting them to dates and sorting them.

```
@files.sort_by {|filename| DateTime.parse(File.mtime(filename).to_s) }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you have is working as you would expect. I've created four files and this is the output by `ls -lt`, which sorts the file by modified time:

```
$ ls -t
2  3  4  1
```

Your example outputs:

```
@files = Dir.entries(Dir.pwd)
@files.sort_by { |file| File.mtime(file) }
=> ["2", ".", "3", "4", "1", ".."]
```

Note: By convention a method in any set does not change the set itself. You need to call `sort_by!` in order to apply the sorted set to the original set.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example should work correct, but it simply return sorted array of files. If you want to change you variable, try mutator `sort_by!`

```
@files.sort_by! {|filename| File.mtime(filename) }
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me!